# .NET MMC Snap-ins in Side-by-side Installation

Tags: .net, windows-installer, mmc

Is it possible to install an MMC snap-in developed with .NET in such a way that multiple versions/instances of the same snap-in are installed on the same system? I'm looking for something like [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) that could be applied to MMC snap-ins somehow since I would like each instance of our product to be truly side-by-side with the other instances.

Alternatively, what is the recommended approach to dealing with side-by-side installations (multi-instance installations) that include MMC snap-ins?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I've ever tried this.  I imagine you could have mutually exclusive components (for each instance) with different COM registration metadata.  Another approach might be to have the snapin be singular but use some kind of reflection/injection to get it to host a different implementation / version of the snap in.

Comment: I don't know if any of the metadata qualifies as "COM" since they're pure .Net code. The have an "Installer" class that gets called to install them as MMC snap-ins, but the implementation is entirely buried in .Net CLR code so it's not really apparent how these things register. I've seen some registry entries and documentation, but am not sure if they can be manipulated for a side-by-side install. MSI seems happy to take self-registering COM components' work over, but seems to assume .Net installers are smarter about self-registering?